# Simulate PostgreSQL Index Without Creating It

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

Is there a way for me to test a new index (i.e. in memory?) without actually creating it yet?

I would like to test it out and see if the Explain Plan is better.

Thanks,

Comment: No add the index and if not better delete it

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you share your query and the index that you are thinking of trying? The explain plan of the current execution would be helpful as well

Comment: There is an extension, [HypoPG](https://github.com/HypoPG/hypopg), that adds supports for hypothetical indexes to PostgreSQL.